# Animating a UITableView's header and footer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, animation, core-animation

I'm struggling to animate the removal of a tableview's header/footer content with animation.  I believe I can call either removeFromSuperview on the header contents itself, or just assign the header to nil, but I don't know how to animate this.  A simple animation block doesn't do anything - how do I fade a view (a label in this case) in/out?

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource instance or some other view controller class? If you're using a UITableViewDataSource, you should use tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section to pragmatically remove headers and tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section to remove footers programmatically.

Comment: I'm using a tableview controller. Just to clarify, I want to fade out the table's header view, not the section header

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wrote an example of how to remove the header view altogether using animation blocks.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This assumes the animation is being called inside of your `UITableViewController` class.

Simply removing the header view from the superview doesn't work because the table view doesn't know to resize itself to fill up what used to be the header view. The setting of the header view causes the table view to animatedly refresh itself.

If this doesn't work, check your assignment(s) of the `tableView` instance.

Answer (score 10):

I ended up with the following simple solution. It animates the removal of the header.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

I realize this is mentioned in WINSergey's response, but I found his explanation a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following two options to both work ok:

option 1

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                      delay:0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{deleteLabel.alpha = 0;}
             completion:nil];
```

option 2

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
deleteLabel.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Just a minor note for anyone following this, the option above should be UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I wanted to control how the header is removed, here is my method :

At ViewDidLoad :

```
UIView *transView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 200.f)];
transView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.headerView = transView;
[transView release];

[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
```

Then when you need to remove header :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3f
                      delay:.0f
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.f, 0.0f);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work perfectly "as is", and I do not care about animation

```
    [myPrettyViewControllerInstance letUpdatePrettyViewNow];
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:[myPrettyViewControllerInstance view]];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

but if we no need it more

```
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:nil];
```

**thats all of we need**, really (if it not fadeout - check the conditions of the

```
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:nil];
```

**and we not need**

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:nil];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

nop

```
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:nil];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

nop

```
    [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:nil];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
```

noo..

Comment: Sorry, but it works for headers (don't know about cells). I use this in my recent project and all are worked. Can you provide source-code?

Comment: It did not work for inserting a table header view.  Using storyboards and auto layout.  The view just appears.  It does not animate in.

Comment: the work code
    
    '- (void)updateAITrackerStatus{'
    
'    AITracker *tracker = [[[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] theAgenda] aiTracker];'
    
    if (tracker) {
        
        [_aiTrackerVC setTracker:tracker];
        
        [_tableView beginUpdates];
        [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:[_aiTrackerVC view]];
        [_tableView endUpdates];
        
    }else{
        
        [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:nil];
    }
}'

Answer (score 0):

I had to put 2 animations to get it working.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        mylbl.alpha = 0.1 ;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
            mylbl.alpha = 1.0 ;
        }];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is doing this, i had to mix all the answers for it work properly inside a `UITableView`. Simply doing `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` weren't adding an animation for me. This allows the footer to be removed and the cells drop down nicely with an animation instead of instantly with a jerk.

```
private func updateFooter(view : UIView?, size : CGFloat){

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    mainTableView.beginUpdates()
    mainTableView.tableFooterView = view
    mainTableView.tableFooterView?.frame.size.height = size
    mainTableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```